# Is it possible to put a photo on a report and for it to disappear when in print view/when printing?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I want my background picture on one of my reports to disappear when printing so the user won't use to much ink since the photo is highly detailed.

Is there a way for it to only show when I'm in Report View and disappear when viewing the Print Preview or when printing?

Answer (score 1):

Change the **Display When** property of the image to `Screen Only`:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for background images?